# Which database to use with android application

Tags: android, database

I am developing an android mobile application using eclipse. I need a database that resides on a desktop computer. I need to save and retrieve information to and from the database to the mobile application. I will be storing details such as login details, registration and location of user. SQLite will not be appropriate for this since the database created will only be accessible by itself. Can I use SQL server for this? I am new to android and I am not sure what database to use and how to save and retrieve information to and from the database to the mobile application. Please help.

Comment: How can you implement **SQL Server** into mobile device ?

Comment: As of now, **ONLY** SQLite is supported among the various databases in Android. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @All  - "I need a database that resides on a desktop computer." read question carefully..

Comment: for desktop computer , use mysql open source, why SQL Server paid one ? simple answer

Comment: You can use anyone (SQL Server, MySQL or ORACLE) as per your need and requirements,but be sure you need a web service to implement to communicate with your desktop server and android application client.

Comment: with any database , SQL Server, MySQL or Oracle , you can easily implement webservice.

Comment: I have worked with all the three, with webservices in java-servlet, php and .net

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. If you can give me a tutorial or site that says how to implement a web service it would be of great help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SQL server to manage the data on your desktop and create a web-service in .Net on Visual Studio.

Then connect to the web-service in your application and set/get data from the DB.

Link on how to make a web-service in .NET (does not include the implementation in Android) : http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx

Links on how to connect your service with Android : http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html

Comment: Is it possible to save data from the mobile application to SQL server through the web service?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! You just need to create different web-services for every operation.

Comment: Please if you can give me a link to a site that says how to implement a web service for this, it would be of great help.

Comment: Yeah, sure I can give you loads of links. But can you please tell me what exactly are you asking for ?  How to create a web-service or how to connect the web-service with your application.. ?

Comment: No problem. I recently developed one project on web-services on Android. Feel free to write me if you need more tutorial links. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best bet if you are using Windows is [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server. It comes with phpmyadmin(Although you do need to get a few tweaks in order to get it up and running correctly). Then it is very easy to use the database(mysql) as you have a graphical interface with phpmyadmin. Ofcourse if youre going to need to access it from your application you would have to provide an intermediary php script to get it working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Ypu can use SQL Server with your mobile app but still u have to use one web service to connect it with **SQL Server DB** or you can also use **WAMP Server** with **MySql DB** that will be easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I would HIGHLY recommend using Sybase SQL Anywhere.  Their UltraLite DB works on Android as well as Windows.  It has a MobilLink Server that allows for two-way data transfer between the PC and the Android device.  You can get the Developer Edition for free from www.sybase.com.  The current installation also includes a fully working Android sample application that includes data synchronization between the PC and Android device.

After all, Sybase wrote SQL Server for Microsoft originally - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Mark